# How to define a "NON-UNIQUE" constraint, asserting existing values on INSERT?

Tags: sql-server, unique-constraint, distinct-values

**UPDATE: I now dismissed the idea behind this question and favored a different design. However, the given answer is a good one for the question as it stands. and I gladly have accepted it.**

---

I want to achieve something like the opposite of the [UNIQUE constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15) in SQL Server.

Upon `INSERT` of a new row, it must be assured, that one of the already existing values is reused for a specific column (Rows using new values must be created otherwise, see note below):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Item]
       (/*...*/
       [LogicalId])
VALUES
       (/*...*/
       123)
GO
```

This must fail, if the value for `LogicalId` is not among the yet existing values.

Because the value for this comes from a `SEQUENCE`, I tried to add a `CONSTRAINT` clause using this `SEQUENCE` like so:

```
ALTER TABLE Item  
ADD CONSTRAINT chkInsertNonUniqueLogicalId 
CHECK 
(
    ( LogicalId <= (SELECT current_value FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'SQ_LogicalId') ) AND
    ( LogicalId >= (SELECT minimum_value FROM sys.sequences WHERE name = 'SQ_LogicalId') ) 
);  
GO
```

But this resulted in an error

> Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed

How to assert for existing values on the same column, when inserting new rows using the `INSERT` command?

Note: rows that should have new logical ID's (not-yet-used values) will be INSERTed with `NULL`, causing a `DEFAULT` constraint with the above mentioned sequence to kick in). The reason for this is to have database-controlled (not user-controlled) logical ids.

Comment: You can use a UDF with a check constraint. That's probably the only way to do what you describe with a check constraint (another option would be to use a trigger (either after or instead of insert).

Comment: Considering that no new values can ever therefore ever be inserted, why not create a new table with all the possible values and then create a foreign key constraint?

Comment: @Larnu There CAN be new values. I just want to disallow having arbitrary values from a user, I want to have them "auto-assigned" by the DB, when the user provides NULL (See note)

Comment: That isn't what you describe in the post at all, @Marcel .You clearly state you want to stop the user creating *new* distinct values in the column. Stopping a User inserted at all into a column, and inserted new distinct values is ***completely*** different. One is permissions based, one is constraint based.

Comment: @Larnu I tried to better explain in the note now. I want to have the database control the id values instead of the user submitting arbitrary values.

Comment: You need to reask your question, at this stage, @Marcel . What you asked in your question, and what you appear to want are 2 completely different things. Changing your question, however, would entirely invalidate my answer, which is really frowned upon by the community. You are better off asking a new question now, and actually explaining what you *really* want, not what you *think* you want. Don't post an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: *rows .... will be inserted with NULL, causing a DEFAULT constraint ..... to kick in* - actually - ***NO*** - if you insert a `NULL` into a column, the default constraint for that column will ***NOT*** kick in! Instead - `NULL` will be stored. The default constraint **only gets used** if you have an `INSERT` that does ***NOT*** provide any value - not even `NULL` - for a given column!

Comment: @marc_s Right! My ideas behind this question seem to be really flawed and I will abandon them eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like an odd requirement when you describe it the way you do, however, that's because like you're looking at this from the wrong angle. What you are after here is certainly a foreign key constraint, it just seems you're missing the table which contains the foreign key.

Therefore, you need to create said table, and then create the foreign key constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Logical (LogicalID int NOT NULL
                          /*,...Other Columns? ...*/ );

ALTER TABLE dbo.Logical ADD CONSTRAINT PK_LogicalID
                        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (LogicalID);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Logical (LogicalID /*,... Other Columns? ...*/)
SELECT DISTINCT LogicalID /*,... Other Columns? ...*/
FROM dbo.Items
WHERE LogicalID IS NOT NULL;
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Items ADD CONSTRAINT FK_LogicalID
                      FOREIGN KEY (LogicalID) REFERENCES dbo.Logical(LogicalID);
```

Comment: This will work, if there are never new LogicalId's but there will. See the comment and note. And I want the Logical Id's assigned by the database not the user.